# How to call PyScript function in HTML?

Tags: html, plot, pyscript

I am making a simple webpage where I need to take number inputs from user, calculate resistance and make a graph. I am using PyScript and matplot lib library to make a graph.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>

    <py-env>
        - matplotlib
    </py-env>

</head>
<body>
    <py-script> print("Graf Ohmovog zakona")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

napon = [12, 20, 30]
jacina = [0.09, 0.12, 0.15]

plt.plot(napon, jacina, marker='o', linestyle='--', color='g', label='otpor(Ω)')


plt.xlabel('Napon(V)')
plt.ylabel('Jačina struje (A)')
plt.title('Graf')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')

fig
</py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

I already added a graph, but now I need to add user input.

---

I created a Python function that should be called wtih HTML button, but for some reason it is not working.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>STEM projekat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>

    <py-env>
        - matplotlib
        //- js
        //- pyodoide
    </py-env>

</head>

<body>

  <div>Napon 1<div>
  <input type="number" id="napon1"/>

  <div>Napon 2<div>
  <input type="number" id="napon2"/>

  <div>Napon 3<div>
  <input type="number" id="napon3"/>

  <div>Jačina 1<div>
  <input type="number" id="jacina1"/>

  <div>Jačina 2<div>
  <input type="number" id="jacina2"/>

  <div>Jačina 3<div>
  <input type="number" id="jacina3"/>

<button type="button" id="button">OK</button>


    <py-script> 
print("loading...")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from js import document 
from pyodide import create_proxy




def runPython():
    print("HI")

    napon1= Element('napon1').element.value
    napon2= Element('napon2').element.value
    napon3= Element('napon3').element.value
    jacina1= Element('jacina1').element.value
    jacina2= Element('jacina2').element.value
    jacina3= Element('jacina3').element.value

    otpor1 = napon1/jacina1
    otpor2 = napon2/jacina2
    otpor3 = napon3/jacina3
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    
    napon = [napon1, napon2, napon3]
    jacina = [jacina1, jacina2, jacina3]
    
    plt.plot(jacina, napon, marker='o', linestyle='--', color='g', label='Country 1')
    
    plt.xlabel('Year')
    plt.ylabel('Population (M)')
    plt.title('Year vs Population')
    plt.legend(loc='lower right')
    
    fig



function_proxy = create_proxy(runPython)

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function_proxy)



</py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

I used code I found on stackoverflow[in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72321468/how-do-i-call-a-python-script-when-clicking-a-button-using-pyscript).

Once I run the code  get the following error from browser debugger:
[Debugger error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO380.png)

Comment: 1) Under `py-env`, what is `pyodoide`? 2) What errors and warnings how in the browser debugger?

Comment: 1)pyodoide is a library. I found that in the answer on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72321468/how-do-i-call-a-python-script-when-clicking-a-button-using-pyscript

Comment: That is my answer. You misspelled the word **pyodide**. Also, you do not put `pyodide` in `py-env`. Pyodide is the framework that PyScript is built upon.

Comment: I placed pyodide in py-env as I didn't know what else to do. So i deleted it now, but function is still not called.

Comment: And I get the following error: Uncaught PythonError: TypeError: runPython() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

    at new_error (pyodide.asm.js:14:238191)
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0xedbcb
    at pyodide.asm.wasm:0xedccc
    at Module._pythonexc2js (pyodide.asm.js:14:932707)
    at Module.callPyObjectKwargs (pyproxy.gen.ts:374:12)
    at Module.callPyObject (pyproxy.gen.ts:384:17)
    at PyProxyClass.apply (pyproxy.gen.ts:1145:19)
    at Object.apply (pyproxy.gen.ts:1022:18)

Comment: What does the browser debugger show once you click the button?

Comment: Please edit your question with new details. Your comment is difficult to read.

Comment: Your function `runPython` must have a parameter (event) and be async. `async def runPython(event)` and you must import `asyncio`.

Comment: Should I put "event" or something else?

Comment: Now I get an error from pyscript

Comment: You can name the parameter anything you want. It is a DOM `event`.

Comment: I am getting an error

Comment: What is the error? Use the browser debugger console tab to review and debug.